# Setting background of input box to Red

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry in advance for being dumb.

I am adding some error checking code to an existing (pre-built) website. I cant change the HTML. The element I need to change is:

`<input type="text" name="Q_5533" size="4" value="1" class="form_input_general">`

It is a quantity box. I need to change the background colour to red. So basically change it to:

`<input type="text" name="Q_5534" style="background-color: #ff3e3e" size="4" value="1" class="form_input_general">`

The element name changes on each page. I can get it in the code by using:

`var QuantityName ="Q_" + sProdRef;`

I am just struggling with getDocument and setAttribute to change it. I realise this is quite basic and I cant see the wood for the trees.

Please could someone help me?

Many thanks

Tony

Comment: You can try `document.getElementsByName(QuantityName)[0].style.background = 'red';`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). It selects elements like CSS selectors:

```js
var quantityName = "Q_" + sProdRef;
var element = document.querySelector('input[name=' + quantityName + ']');
element.style.backgroundColor = '#ff3e3e';
```

Comment: Thank you Peter. This works well. Not sure which of the 2 answers is more efficient to use?

Comment: Juan's `getElementsByName` is probably a bit faster than my `querySelector` because it doesn't have to parse the selector. `querySelector` however is more flexible.

Comment: getElementsByName is a bit faster, but just a bit, from what I see on this jsperf suite:
https://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementbyid/35 It won't really make much of a difference which one you use.

Answer (score 1):

Use getElementsByName, it returns a collection, so the first match should do it, like this:

```
var sProdRef = '5533'; // set somewhere before

var QuantityName ="Q_" + sProdRef;
document.getElementsByName(QuantityName)[0].style.backgroundColor='red';
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pwwm169d/

Comment: Thank you Juan. That is perfect. I was missing the [0] and then went off on the wrong tangent :)